# Why did Django creators separate model and queryset?

Tags: django

My question is just same as the title;

Why did Django creators separate model and queryset?

While writing Django codes, I always feel that both are playing a very similar role in that they are both for Database management. And plus, it feels a bit awkward that model itself doesn't have actual data, but pass them to queryset, despite that it is a interface between python and database.

Are there any reasons why the Django creator, or collaborators divide the same role by the two?

Comment: In Object oriented sense, they are two totally different things. A Model instance is an object that can represent anything you want it to represent, like a Car, an Address or a Person, with some of it's properties stored in a database. (it can include properties that don't even come from the database). A QuerySet is deferred database query, that can return one or multiple database rows. What do you mean by "separate" and by "model itself doesn't have actual data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an object oriented sense, they are two totally different things:

- A `Model` instance is an object that can represent anything you want it to represent, like a Car, an Address or a Person, with some of its properties stored in a database (it can include properties that don't even come from the database).
- A `QuerySet` is a deferred database query, that can return one or multiple database rows. When evaluating the `QuerySet` you actually instantiate the Models and populate them with data.

Note that in MVC terms, Django Models are exactly the Model of MVC. You could also have your own models that aren't even subclassing `django.db.models.Model`, e.g. if you fetch the data from an API, or a model that only lives in the current session and isn't permanently stored in the database.